# Redis data retrieval

Tags: java, caching, redis

I have a map in redis cache with the following structure :

Cache entry : `Map<String, Map<String, String>>`

The inner map could have as many as 25000 elements/buckets.
Is there a way in redis to retrieve a specific value from the inner map based on the keys(redis key, outer map's key and inner map's key) without having to fetch the entire redis entry in my Java method that accesses this redis cache?

Currently, if I have to delete a particular key from the inner map, am doing it the following way :

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> mapFromRedis = redis.get("myRediscacheKey");
Map<String, String> innerMap = new HashMap<>();
if (!mapFromRedis.isEmpty()) {
    innerMap = mapFromRedis.get("key");
}
if (innerMap.containsKey("keyToBeDeleted")) {
    innerMap.remove("keyToBeDeleted");
    mapFromRedis.put("key", innerMap);
}
redis.set("myRediscacheKey", mapFromRedis);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure has 3-level mapping: *Redis key*, *outer map key*, and *inner map key*. From your example, we can get the following mapping: `myRediscacheKey -> key -> keyToBeDeleted -> value`

However, Redis can only has at most 2-level mapping, i.e. [HASH](http://redis.io/commands#hash). In order to achieve your goal, you have to do *compress* the 3-level mapping to a 2-level mapping, or even 1-level mapping.

> Compress to 2-level mapping

You can combine the Redis key with your outer map key as the key of a `HASH`, and take the inner map key as the field of the `HASH`. In that way, we can get the 2-level mapping as follows: `myRediscacheKey:key -> keyToBeDeleted -> value`.

```
// set inner map key
hset myRediscacheKey:key keyToBeDeleted value
// remove inner map key
hdel myRediscacheKey:key keyToBeDeleted
```

> Compress to 1-level mapping

You can also combine the 3 keys into one key: `myRediscacheKey:key:keyToBeDeleted -> value`

```
// set inner map key
set myRediscacheKey:key:keyToBeDeleted value
// remove inner map key
del myRediscacheKey:key:keyToBeDeleted
```

Comment: Do we really need to modify the logical structure of the cache (Map of Maps in OP's case) just to make operations more efficient? Moving the difficult job to an UDF is much easier and keeps your code intact. Your solution should be preferred if UDFs cannot be placed on the Redis instance (due to some restrictions)

Comment: @kgdinesh It depends on what's OP wants to achieve. Intact code or better performance? Since OP mentioned that there're 25000 elements in the inner map, I think he might want better performance. Also it's NOT a good idea to have the lua script do some complicated work, that might block Redis for a long time.

Comment: doing complicated things is exactly why UDFs are for isn't it? Why would it block redis? how different is it from making the similar call via a client?

Comment: NO! DO NOT do complicated things in lua scripts. Redis is single-threaded, and the lua script runs in an atomic way. So, when Redis is executing a lua script, it CANNOT process any other requests. That's what I mean blocking Redis. You can get more details from the [documentation](http://redis.io/commands/EVAL#atomicity-of-scripts)

Comment: Agreed, so your solution allows for more concurrency than that of UDF, which shouldn't be significant, given the UDF does only a couple of GETs and one DEL. So, the deciding factor comes down to whether this advantage is worth modifying the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it with [Redisson](https://redisson.org). It allows to reference Redis object to another Redis object though special reference objects which handled by Redisson. Here is the code sample:

```
RMap<String, RMap<String, String>> mapFromRedis = redisson.getMap("myRediscacheKey");

// Redisson loads only small reference object 
// to another Redis map and NOT entire map
Map<String, String> innerMap = mapFromRedis.get("key");

if (innerMap.remove("keyToBeDeleted") != null) {
   // key has been deleted
}
// or with faster approach
if (innerMap.fastRemove("keyToBeDeleted") == 1) {
   // key has been deleted
}
```

That's it! You don't need to execute huge update on each inner map change. Under the hood it works using only 2 operations over Redis: `get` and `hdel`

`RMap` extends standard Java `Map` and `ConcurrentMap` interfaces. Thus you don't need to handle with keys/connections/serialization. This all done by Redisson.